# How to add members to an event

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have to connect to an event like that.

```
for (int iii = 1; iii <= pcdApplication.Machines.Count; iii++)
{
    Machine machine = pcdApplication.Machines.Item(iii);
    machineList.Add(machine);
    machine.ErrorMsg += Machine_ErrorMsg;
}
```

the connected event is the following:

```
private void Machine_ErrorMsg(string Msg, int ErrorType)
{
    ... 
}
```

so here I have no indication of what is the sender machine which I would need to know its properties.

Thanks

Patrick

Comment: This is an example of why any events you define should follow the .NET convention, even if you think they don't need to. If the author of that event had done so, you'd have a `sender` and there'd be no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only thing you could do would be to use a lambda instead of a named method, e.g.

```cs
for (int iii = 1; iii <= pcdApplication.Machines.Count; iii++)
{
    Machine machine = pcdApplication.Machines.Item(iii);
    machineList.Add(machine);
    machine.ErrorMsg += (Msg, ErrorType) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(machine.Name);

                            // ...
                        };
}
```

The lambda has access to variables from the current context, which a named method does not.

Comment: That is sooo clever! Had not thought about it! Thanks a bunch

Comment: @Patrick Do note that lambdas make it much more difficult to unregister events, and not unregistering events may lead to memory leaks if you are not careful.

Comment: @JonasH, certainly a good point. I've never actually tried it myself but I guess the thing to do there might be to have a `Dictionary` assigned to a field where the keys were the objects raising the events and the values were the lambdas handling them. That would enable deregistering those lambdas from those events later.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, something like that. The important thing is to assign the lambda to a delegate, so you are using the same delegate object when registering and unregistering.